# Disappeared RAID 1 array after replacing motherboard

Tags: mount, raid, mdadm

I ran into a huge issue. I planned to replace the motherboard in my HTPC, it was assembled but it turned out that my new mb is faulty and I had to put back the old one. My old Ubuntu 20.04.2 is booted, all drives mounted except the RAID 1 ARRAY (sdc and sdd). I figured it out that the new motherboard's UEFI bios probably deleted the superblocks from the raided HDDs.
I checked these:

`blkid` says to both hdds: PTUUID=".....hjhkkfhsdk....." PTTYPE="gpt"

`lsblk` says nothing on neither drives, TYPE: disk

`mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dec/sdd1`
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sdc1: No such file or directory
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 has no superblock - assembly aborted

`mdadm --run /dev/md0`
mdadm: error opening /dev/md0: No such file or directory

`mount /md0 /mnt/Storage`
mount: /mnt/Storage: special device /md0 does not exist

It would be good to find a solution, because there are important data on the array.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I also had an issue once. Keep calm. mdadm is a solid application.  I got things working again after using "Boot repair disk"  Look at for some tips: https://askubuntu.com/questions/504064/my-older-computer-has-become-unbootable-except-for-ubuntu-minimal-cd-raid-md

Comment: PC is working well, just md0 disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get back the data. I commented out the old array in /etc/mdadm.conf, then:

- created a new raid array:
  `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --verbose --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd`
- saved the layout:
  `mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`
  `update-initramfs -u`

mdad said: "partition table exists on /dev/sdc but will be lost or meaningless after creating array" but after mounting all the data was available on /dev/md0.